# Method to sort List of Lists based on Sublist

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Lists consisting of `int` arrays:

```
(List<List<int[]>>)
```

I want to sort the list of lists based on the first index in the `int` array in the first element of the lists. 
My solution so far is:

```
List<List<int[]>> myList = new List<List<int[]>> { new List<int[]> { new int[] { 1, 5 }, new int[] { 2, 4 } }, new List<int[]> { new int[] { 3, 4 }, new int[] { 0, 1 } } };
myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Max(y => y[0])).ToList();
```

In which the result is that the second list comes first and the first would come second.

But I don't like that one as performance is a critical point and I don't like to execute the `Max` operation as it is useless.

So, is there a better way?

-

EDIT: I finished using:

```
myList.OrderByDescending(x => x[0][0]).ToList();
```

As proposed by CodeCaster in the comments. This one was faster in my code than the option proposed by Aldert. But his answer is worth viewing too.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including example input and output. You have a list of lists of arrays. By which array from the second list do you want to sort? Do you want to `rootList.OrderByDescending(l => l[0][0])`?

Comment: I can add an example, but I think that will be of no use, as it is not about an error in my code. No I want to sort the lists in my list based on the first index of the sublist (one of the sublists of list of lists) as stated in the question. So your example does not do the job.

Comment: Okay, I will add it soon

Comment: If "performance is a critical point", then why are you using LINQ? Why not just use [`List`'s Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx), or implement the appropriate sorting algorithm for your data set?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Sorry, while creating the example I realised, I mixed thinks up and your solution will do the job. Thanks!

Comment: @KennethK. Thanks for thinking with me beyond the question! Do you think they will be faster? Is there a faster way to order a list on descending order with the sorting algorithm you proposed than with linq?

Comment: You should profile the code and determine which is faster for your environment.

Comment: If someone would mind adding an answer, I can mark this one as resolved. Or probably as duplicate, as the answer was easier than I expected. (Which may have been the reason why I couldn't find it)

Comment: I just looked at your code and you pickup the first element of the array, is that the idea or do you need the max of the int too?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea, I do not need the max of the index. Just the first element for both the list and the array. So the answer given by CodeCaster is exact what I searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer you are looking for with a binary compare, it is fairly simple because it takes the first element out of the sublint and out of the array (as you where looking for).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int[]>> mainList = new List<List<int[]>>();



            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                List<int[]> subList = new List<int[]>();

                int limj = rand.Next(5);
                for (int j = 0; j < 5 + limj; j++)
                {
                    int limk = rand.Next(5);
                    int[] arrayInt = new int[limk + 5];
                    for (int k = 0; k < limk + 5; k++)
                    {
                        arrayInt[k] = rand.Next(200);
                    }
                    subList.Add(arrayInt);

                }
                mainList.Add(subList);

            }

            mainList.Sort(new MaxComparer(false));

            foreach (List<int[]> oneL in mainList)
            {
                foreach (int[] arrayList in oneL)
                {
                    foreach (int i in arrayList) Console.Write(i + " ");
                    Console.Write("|");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

        public class MaxComparer : IComparer<List<int[]>>
        {
            bool order = false;
            public MaxComparer(bool Order)
            {
                order = Order;


            }

            public int Compare(List<int[]> x, List<int[]> y)
            {

                return x[0][0].CompareTo(y[0][0]) * (order ? 1 : -1);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your effort! I tested your method against the one presented by CodeCaster in the comments. Your option took 1.2121 ms and CodeCaster's took 0.8996 ms. This may not seem to be a huge difference, but I need to perform this action a few thousand times. Therefore, I will use the one presented by CodeCaster.

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you tell me how big your main list is (Count)?

Comment: The main list has 2899 indices, the sublists average about 1500 and the int array 3

Comment: This is why the method of CodeCaster is faster. Try to make a list with 1Milj :-)

Comment: I did test it with a list of over 20 million. My results: 

1st run: CodeCaster 6015 ms, your method 15235 ms. 
2nd run; your method: 15161 ms, Codecaster: 5760 ms.

(The second run was executed in reversed order)
So CodeCasters method seems to be faster.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing so. Very useful information when considering sorting and filtering!

Answer (score 1):

This code is sorting asc or desc depending on the order you pass to the comparer. It runs O*1 over the elements, to setup the structure to be able to compare. I would be interesting to know if it works faster for you (I do think only with very big trees). When you would sort all the inner lists already, you do not need to keep a helper dictionary, you can then take the last element.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> mainList = new List<List<int>>();

            List<int> newList = new List<int>();


            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                int ra = rand.Next(200);

                if (i % 5  == 0)
                {
                    if (newList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        newList = new List<int>();
                        mainList.Add(newList);
                    }
                }
                newList.Add(ra);

            }

            mainList.Sort( new MaxComparer(mainList, false));

            foreach (List<int> oneL in mainList)
            {
                foreach (int oneInt in oneL)
                {
                    Console.Write(oneInt + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

        public class MaxComparer : IComparer<List<int>>
        {
            bool order = false;
            Dictionary<int, int> helper = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            public MaxComparer(List<List<int>> sortList, bool Order)
            {
                order = Order;

                foreach (List<int> oneL in sortList)
                {
                    int max = int.MinValue;
                    foreach (int oneInt in oneL)
                    {
                        if (max < oneInt) max = oneInt;
                    }
                    helper.Add(oneL.GetHashCode(), max);
                }
            }

            public int Compare(List<int> x, List<int> y)
            {
                return helper[x.GetHashCode()].CompareTo(helper[y.GetHashCode()]) * (order ? 1:-1);

            }
        }
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like to know that too, but I think you missed the fact that the sublist is an int array.

Comment: No worries, i can make it e level deeper, i have a look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Select(y => y.Select(z => z).OrderBy(z => z))).ToList();
```

EDIT: I forgot to go one layer deeper. The error was caused because it wanted to order an arrayobject instead of its elements.

Comment: Yes, the 'Select' function without specification is exactly the one I was looking for, thanks! The option proposed by CodeCaster in the comments works fine too, but this one is in line with what I expected and the first working answer.

Comment: I expected it to work, but your code is giving an error while running. It states 'at least one object must implement Icomparable'. So, no this is not the first working answer.

Comment: My bad! i forgot to add FirstOrDefault. It should work now!

Comment: Nope, it still throws the same exception

Comment: Thanks for your effort so far, but I'm terribly sorry, this does throw the same error again...